# Search within the text of an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to search words within a specific web page element using webBrowser control API in C# (winforms) or using an injected java script.

I used the following java script and injected it into the loaded web page:

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {

 var strFound;

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  else if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }

 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
```

This code works for the entire page, but I want to search within the inner text of a specific element. How can I limit my search to such an element?

Comment: What's the element, do you have id of the element, name or other attribute?

Comment: How are you specifying "a specific element"? I mean, if you can refer a specific element, you can simply get its `innerText` without `TextRange` object. Notice, that in the legacy model you're using, a text range can be created on `body`, `button`, `textarea` or `input type="text"` only. Then you can use some methods of `TextRange` object to move the range, also to a specific element.

Comment: @Teemu it is a division, I guess I must use moveToElementText

Comment: @Ahmad yes you should :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to:**

1. Add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml.dll`
2. Then get [`IHTMLBodyElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704297(v=vs.85).aspx) from body using `webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement`
3. Then find your tag and get [`IHTMLElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx) from your tag.
4. Then get the [`IHtmlTextRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741548(v=vs.85).aspx) from body using [`createTextRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536401(v=vs.85).aspx)
5. Then limit the search to your tag using [`moveToElementText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536630(v=vs.85).aspx)
6. Then find the string from the range using [`findText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422(v=vs.85).aspx)
7. Then if the string found, you can [`select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741545(v=vs.85).aspx) it.

### Example

Here is a working example that we find `"some"` text in `"div2"` while we have 2 `div` elements, `div1` and `div2` and both of them contains `"some"` text.

**Form**

Create a `Form` and put a `WebBrowser` control on `Form1` and write this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Load += Form1_Load;
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate(@"D:\file.html");
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var searchText="some";
    var body = webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement as IHTMLBodyElement;
    var tag= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("div2").DomElement as IHTMLElement;

    var range = body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(tag);
    if (range.findText(searchText, searchText.Length, 0))
        range.select();
    else
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("String '{0}' not found.", searchText));
}
```

**Sample Html Content**

Here is the content of `file.html` for test:

```
<html>
<head><title>Select content</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Here is some content</div>
    <div id="div2">Here is some other content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot**

And here is the screenshot:

[image]

**Note**

- You may need to add some null checking to your code.
- You can find the element using other attributes, for example using the name attribute:
- For a javascript solution, you can take a look at [Ahmad answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33788349/3110834)

```
var tag = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.All.GetElementsByName("somename")
              .Cast<HtmlElement>()
              .FirstOrDefault().DomElement as IHTMLElement;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I also used the `moveToElementText` in my answer to this question. Now, I have modified my java script function. I remember that I had some problems with highlighting the selected text in some situations when I used `mshtml` API, then I switched to this script and it is still in testing stage

Comment: @Ahmad Thank you for your feedback. Your answer is completely OK and a good script answer for who knows how to inject this script in the document +1 to your question and answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The following java script which uses `moveToElementText` in the first call (when the `TRange` is null) works

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {

 var strFound;

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  else if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   var elem = document.getElementById('my_elem');
   // go to the element text
   TRange.moveToElementText(elem);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }

 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to get a DOM Reference of your Element. Following that, you could use JQuery to filter the textnodes in your Element like:

```
  $($element.contents()).filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3; // filter textnodes only

  }).each(function(){

    findString(this.textContent);
  });
```

Comment: Or plain: document.getElementById('header').childNodes.filter(function(node){return node.nodeType===3 }).forEach(function(node){findString(node.textContent);}) - you need to convert childNodes to an array